# Error creating iOS Static Library using CMake

Tags: ios, cmake, static-libraries

I'm trying to create a static library of the project [json11](https://github.com/dropbox/json11) with CMake, to use in a iOS project.

I had created a sample project here: https://github.com/4brunu/json11CMakeiOS

When building the json11 target it work's fine, but the json11_test target return's the following error:

```
=== BUILD TARGET json11_test OF PROJECT example_all WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies
target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.tool', but there's no such product type for the 'iphoneos' platform

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
```

The original json11 [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/4brunu/json11CMakeiOS/blob/master/deps/json11/CMakeLists.txt) is this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(json11 VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

enable_testing()

add_library(json11 json11.cpp)
target_include_directories(json11 PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
target_compile_options(json11
  PUBLIC -std=c++11
  PRIVATE -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -Wall -Wextra -Werror)
configure_file("json11.pc.in" "json11.pc" @ONLY)

add_executable(json11_test test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(json11_test json11)

install(TARGETS json11 DESTINATION lib)
install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/json11.hpp" DESTINATION include)
install(FILES "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/json11.pc" DESTINATION lib/pkgconfig)
```

After some test's, I had modified the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/4brunu/json11CMakeiOS/blob/master/deps/json11/CMakeLists_no_tests.txt) and it works, but I'm trying to figure out what's wrong.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(json11 VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

enable_testing()

add_library(json11 json11.cpp)
target_include_directories(json11 PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
target_compile_options(json11
  PUBLIC -std=c++11
  PRIVATE -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -Wall -Wextra -Werror)
configure_file("json11.pc.in" "json11.pc" @ONLY)

# Commented this two lines
# add_executable(json11_test test.cpp)
# target_link_libraries(json11_test json11)

install(TARGETS json11 DESTINATION lib)
install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/json11.hpp" DESTINATION include)
install(FILES "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/json11.pc" DESTINATION lib/pkgconfig)
```

Not sure if the issue is in the CMake configuration [1](https://github.com/4brunu/json11CMakeiOS/blob/master/run_cmake_ios.sh) [2](https://github.com/4brunu/json11CMakeiOS/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt),  the [iOS toolchain](https://github.com/4brunu/json11CMakeiOS/blob/master/cmake/Toolchains/iOS.cmake), [json11 CMake](https://github.com/4brunu/json11CMakeiOS/blob/master/deps/json11/CMakeLists.txt), or any other thing.

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**

I have not found a solution but rather a work around, making the tests optional.

https://github.com/4brunu/json11CMakeiOS/commit/972f00b646057a513d14a90b874f9f398fcff873
https://github.com/dropbox/json11/pull/66

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the test target that comes with the library. In C and C++ you usual have a dedicated command line executable that runs a test suite. On OSX there is target type for that called *Command Line Tool*. Xcode references target types with a reverse DNS identifier, in this case `com.apple.product-type.tool`. On iOS you do not have a target type for command line tools because, well, there is no *public* command line that you could run the executable from.

That being said, you have already found the solution yourself: deactivate the test target generation in CMake for that library if you want to build for iOS.

Comment: I found the solution, but I was wondering what was the cause. Thanks